# Change date format with PostgreSQL (AWS Redshift) from 'M/D/YYYY' to 'DD/MM/YYYY' for Qlik Sense date picker extension

Tags: date, datepicker, amazon-redshift, qliksense

I am trying to change the format of a timestamp field to a date field in a certain format with AWS Redshift.

I googled a lot and the common "best practice" that I found was to cast the timestamp to a date and then use to_char to bring it into the right format. In the end I want to use the date field in a Qlik Sense dashboard where it is input for a date picker extension that apparently requires the format DD/MM/YYYY to work.

Current date format in the DB:
`9/2/2019 6:38:00 AM` (which I would describe as M/D/YYYY H:MM:SS ZZ)

Desired output:
`DD/MM/YYYY`, resulting in the value 02/09/2019

Current status:
`to_char(cast(timestamp_field as date), 'DD/MM/YYYY')` --> result: 02/09/2019

However, the date picker extension in Qlik Sense still does not work and I guess that's because the output is a string and not a date. Casting the string to a date returns in an error.

```
cast(to_char(cast(timestamp_field as date), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as date) as date_picker_date
```

> Connector reply error: SQL##f - SqlState: 57014, ErrorCode: 30,
>   ErrorMsg: [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying
>   to execute a query: [SQLState 57014] ERROR:  Error converting text to
>   date

I am new to Redshift and would have expected to be able to cast to date with a format string as parameter, but apparently that's not a thing. Can someone enlighten me on how to solve this?

Comment: you say "Current date format in the DB: 9/2/2019 6:38:00 AM" - do you mean this is a string field that looks like a date? or a date where your IDE is displaying it that way? in a DB dates are dates - they dont have a display format like that. and it seems unlikely that qlik is requiring a date field to be in s specific format (as that is nonsensical)

Comment: No in the DB it's an actual timestamp. You are right, I looked in Qliksense where it was displayed with AM/PM. In the DB it's 2019-09-02 06:38:01.259000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the timestamp at the beginning of the script of the QlikSense.
It will be at the start of the script. in the Main section as shown below:

```
SET TimestampFormat='M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss[.fff] TT';
```

here SET is being used to define the time stamp in that application.
You can try changing here to your requirements. 
Else 2 options 1 use a stamp which you have already used or create your own extension from the lib
Stamp use can be like this:

```
Datestamp_Table:
Load *,
Date(Date#(StringDate,'M/D/YY'),'DD/MMM/YY') as Date;
LOAD * INLINE [
StringDate
8/7/97
8/6/97];
```

Output will be like this:

```
Stringdate   Date
8/7/97       07/Aug/97
8/6/97       06/Aug/97
```

Comment: Wow sometimes it can be so simple.. changing the timestamp and date format in the initial SET section of the Qlik Sense app did the trick. Thank you so much!